# I have executables in my $PATH which are not listed in my .bashrc file. Where are they coming from?

Tags: bash, terminal, environment-variables

When I open my .bash_profile file I see my path set as

```
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
```

When I run $PATH from my terminal I see

```
-bash: /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

It is my understanding that the PATH is set by the .bashrc file or the .bash_profile. I deleted my .bashrc file. So how are the extra executable paths getting added to my PATH env variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) is the list of bash startup files.

- `/etc/profile`
- `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` or `~/.profile`

Check those files, as they source other files as well. In `/etc/environment` there are system-wide environment variables as well, at least in [Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables).

Comment: and also all the files that are sourced by /etc/profile

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I did not realize these additional files